# Storing different NaN value in variable

Tags: javascript, floating-point, nan

I figured there was nothing preventing code from storing a NaN-value different from the global `NaN` in a variable. However, i quickly experienced that this was dependent on the browser. Storing such a value in a variable worked just fine in Chrome (Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)), while it did not in Firefox (61.0.1 (64-bit)).

Is behavior regarding this not clear from the spec, or does FF not fully follow it here? Why does FF convert the number to the value of the global `NaN`?

Here is a related snippet for testing:

```js
let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(8);
let float = new Float64Array(buffer);
let bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);

float[0] = NaN
bytes[0] = 1;

let differentNaN = float[0];

float[0] = differentNaN;

console.log(`We are ${bytes[0] === 0 ? "not" : "potentially"} on chrome!`);
```

Comment: Nice find. I checked and storing the special NaN value in a variable works in FF (differentNaN !== NaN), it is the assignment back to float that clears the bit.

Comment: @niry Note that `NaN !== NaN` always (and for all different NaN values, as they are identical to ecmascript, even `Object.is(differentNaN, NaN) === true`). You'd need to check the actual implementation or throw memory hooks into FF to find out whether the internal representation differs. As described in the answer, anything showing they are different values is an artifact from the specific implementation, not something desired (FF, in a way, has even better behavior here).

Comment: ASDFGerte, of course. My point about storing is not correct, and I can't tell because just doing `float[0] = float[0]` on FF will clear that bit, but not so on Chrome or node. So not about storing as much as assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**6.1.6** The Number Type](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type) explains this fully:

> [...] except that the 9007199254740990 (that is, 2<sup>53</sup>-2) distinct
>   “Not-a-Number” values of the IEEE Standard are represented in
>   ECMAScript as a single special NaN value. (Note that the NaN value is
>   produced by the program expression NaN.) **In some implementations,
>   external code might be able to detect a difference between various
>   Not-a-Number values, but such behaviour is implementation-dependent;
>   to ECMAScript code, all NaN values are indistinguishable from each
>   other.**

along with the below

> **Note**
>
> The bit pattern that might be observed in an ArrayBuffer (see 24.1) or
>   a SharedArrayBuffer (see 24.2) after a Number value has been stored
>   into it is not necessarily the same as the internal representation of
>   that Number value used by the ECMAScript implementation.

---

I knew i had seen something like this in the spec before, but somehow didn't find it in my research before posting the question, and still took 40 minutes to find it after posting (i must be blind).